# Como dar um select e trazer o top 1 de cada grupo?

Tags: sql, sql-select

Tenho uma table de processos. Ou seja, cada vez que um processo é executado, ele gera uma linha nova. Quero dar um `select` trazendo a última execução de cada processo. Segue table exemplo:

```
Id|ProcessoNome|Situação|DataInicio
1 |RPA_001     |sucesso |03/10/2018
2 |RPA_002     |sucesso |04/10/2018
3 |RPA_003     |erro    |04/10/2018
4 |RPA_003     |sucesso |04/10/2018
5 |RPA_001     |sucesso |04/10/2018
```

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados (e versão): Oracle Database? MariaDB? PostgreSQL? SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Você precisa da última execução de cada processo, certo? Segue abaixo uma query que resolve esse cenário.

```
select distinct nome_processo,
  (select max(data)
     from processos p2
    where p1.nome_processo = p2.nome_processo) as ULTIMA_EXECUCAO
  from processos p1;
```

Exemplo de dados:

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+------------+
| id | nome_processo | status_processo | data       |
+----+---------------+-----------------+------------+
|  1 | RPA_001       | sucesso         | 2018-10-03 |
|  2 | RPA_002       | sucesso         | 2018-10-04 |
|  3 | RPA_003       | erro            | 2018-10-05 |
|  4 | RPA_003       | sucesso         | 2018-10-04 |
|  5 | RPA_001       | sucesso         | 2018-10-04 |
|  6 | RPA_002       | sucesso         | 2018-10-06 |
+----+---------------+-----------------+------------+
```

Retorno da query :

```
+---------------+------------+---+
| nome_processo | ULTIMA_EXECUCAO|
+---------------+----------------+
| RPA_001       | 2018-10-04     |
| RPA_002       | 2018-10-06     | 
| RPA_003       | 2018-10-05     | 
+---------------+----------------+
```

Qualquer dúvida estamos aí, boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão é você ordenar a `data` de execução no `select`.

```
SELECT *FROM tb_processos
ORDER BY data_inicio DESC;
```

O restante é ideal tratar diretamente no código.